# Class not working after render html ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, swiper.js

I use library from [Swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/).

My html :

```
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div id="reswiper"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination split-slider-pagination-he d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"></div>
  
</div>
```

This is my ajax :

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'/getproductDetail',
   datatType: 'json',
   data: {
     "id": id,
     "_token": csrf
   },
   success:function(data) {
     $("#reswiper").html(data.html);
   }
});
```

And this is my view:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
  @foreach ($product->photo_product as $photo)
    <div class="swiper-slide split-slide">
      <img src="{{ $photo->photo }}" >
    </div>      
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

After success, my image will show up. But other class like pagination or navigation button will not work properly.

Comment: add Swiper script in the Before </body> tag section:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i try it but not working

Comment: they have many [demos](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/2w4f2s?file=%2Findex.html), what is  the [pagination](https://swiperjs.com/demos#pagination) you are doing?

Comment: its same like demo u show. but when I enter image data there it uses ajax. the class swiper function does not work perfectly.

Comment: after this [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1053), you should should init Swiper after Ajax request.

Comment: can answer it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function that init the Swiper like [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/2w4f2s?file=%2Findex.html%3A73%2C1-85%2C12) in your ajax success:

```
document.ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/getproductDetail',
        datatType: 'json',
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_token": csrf
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $("#reswiper").html(data.html);
            var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
                pagination: {
                    el: ".swiper-pagination",
                    type: "progressbar",
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can try to call this [event](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-update) `swiper.update()`.

Comment: U right bro,, i try this it work. but i should change id `#swiper` position to `<div class="swiper" id="reswiper">` then div to pagination or navigation are put on data view. otherwise, it won't work.